# OLS regression versus multilevel modelling

Tags: regression, multilevel-analysis

I am working with a survey that includes student scores (level 1) and teacher characteristics (level 2). Students are nested within classes/teachers. I am interested in exploring the relationship between teacher characteristics (IV) and student scores (DV).

To keep it simple, I am inclined to do OLS regression rather than multilevel modeling. That is, to  regress the average score for the classes on teacher characteristics. This would allow me to model the relationship between teachers and their classes mean scores. I am not interested in exploring how the relationship between IV and DV varies among classes.

I know this approach would violate the OLS regression assumption of independent errors, but on the other side I don't see what I may gain using multilevel analysis.

Comment: You might gain valid inferences.